# Stripe Warning Webhook

Tags: magento2, configuration, stripe

Can anyone know about this warning : [image]

how can I remove this warning?

I have already execute webhook:configure command and add webhook at stripe manually also
and this is multiwebsite

please help me about this

Answer (score 0):

some problem here, are you able to remove it?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/206364)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your web hook is setup correctly and working, check this in your stripe account on the stripe website, at time of writing this is here https://dashboard.stripe.com/webhooks

In your database remove all rows in the table stripe_webhooks
Then in your ssh shell run magento stripe:webhooks:configure
Refresh your admin view and the message should be gone